# Weird Weight painting on a rigged character?

Tags: weight-painting

I've successfully rigged the armature to the whole mesh but, weight is kinda weird. It's an armored character, the problem is that the armor pieces doesn't follow the movement correctly. Even if i try to paint it in ordrer to fit the bones' movement, it's doesn't work !
[image]

Comment: ... maybe you should add some more information to your question? It is very broad. Can you edit it?

Comment: Added blend file, i can't post pictures on the main post, don't have enough " reputation"

Comment: I see nothing bad in it. Can you spot a special part which causes the problem?

Comment: the torso mostly

Comment: OK... the gap between the 2 parts... They are not weighted equally. As far as I know, nothing magical can be done here (even if this is a paladin...). You can try to use a blur brush or try to weight copy the inner part of the armor to the outer part (making them two separated meshes before).

Comment: alright, how do you weight copy the part to the another ?

Comment: In short, select the 2 meshes, enter weight paint mode, and use the menu "weights" and "transfer weights" (but I have no time to provide a full answer right now)

Comment: Quick process description here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stem2OPRAyA

Comment: Well i dit it, the gap is still there